# AOL Mail will only load in basic mode

Tags: email

I cannot get AOL mail to load without switching to basic mode, in Firefox 3.5.6 or IE 8. OS is XP Media Center.

The page loads but the area where the inbox should be continues to display "loading" with the little circle going round and round.

What I have tried so far:

  Cleared browser cache
  Reinstalled Java
  Reinstalled Firefox
  Firefox portable from USB drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is RealPlayer installed? I ask because I was having similar problems with an extension that Real adds called "RealPlayer Browser Record Plugin" - disabling that extension solved the problems I was having on random sites.

If that doesn't solve it, you may also want to check the security software (CA, Norton, McAffee) that's installed. Some programs will drown you in pop-ups and clicking the wrong answer can totally screw with all sorts of things.

Of note, some security programs are more trouble than they are worth. For home users I tend to recommend Microsoft's new [Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/security_essentials/) - its more than enough protection for most home users, its unobtrusive, and relatively light on resources.

Comment: No Real-player extension is not installed.

Comment: Uninstalled CA security suite, and it started working. Installed MS Security Essentials, it still works and the computer is noticeably faster, not just browsing but shut down and start up as well.